# VS 2013 RC allows to call functions using curly braces

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

To my surprise VS 2013 compiled this without a error:

```cpp
#include <utility>

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_pair{123, 12.3f};
    return 0;
}
```

Is this some new feature or what? Probably a bug...

Edit: VS 2013 RC now allows to call member functions this way too.

Comment: U kidding? Those are labmda functions, introduced in C++11. Freakin' great feature. BTW the MS C++ compiler is C++11 compliant since VS2012, if I'm not mistaken. Enjoy the power!

Comment: @anhoppe, That is not a lambda.

Comment: GCC and Clang do not compile this. I'm pretty sure it's a bug, as I can't think of any situation where it would be allowed, either.

Comment: And how is `auto main() -> int` better than `int main()`?

Comment: There is no VS2013 yet. A preview version is available, but this question will be highly misleading if anyone reads it once VS2013 is released.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is uniform initialization. Or not?

Comment: @ddriver, If `std::make_pair` was a type, yes. If it followed `Type var{init};` yes.

Comment: @chris - but isn't a constructor effectively a function as well? I mean it if works for the one, why not for the other?

Comment: @ddriver I'm just trying out c++11 features, so I can't say if it's better or not yet. But so far trailing return type feels good for some reason.

Comment: @hvd I've updated title.

Comment: @ddriver, Because a function call is not really initialization. Inside the braces must be a value to initialize it to, or arguments for the constructor to initialize it (because that's what it's for), or the values of an initializer list.

Comment: I assume we are talking about auto main -> int? This basically boils down to int main(). For what's it worth g++ 4.7.2 with c++0x support compiles but that's not an guarantee for standard correctness.

Comment: It doesnt compile on VS2012

Comment: @FuleSnabel No, it's about curly braces after `make_pair`.

Comment: @anhoppe You're mistaken.  VC++11 supports a small (but useful) subset of C++11, but is far from C++11 compliant (and some really nice features are missing).

Answer (score 0):

That feature is apart of the upcoming C++14 standard .. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Function_return_type_deduction